# Could philosophy be top-down?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, linguistics

Could it be that, in the way that mathematics is based on set theory (at least the standard one) or another framework and is built bottom-up from that, philosophy starts from relationships between words and uses linguistics to build from the top down?

Comment: What is bottom-down? I only know bottom-up and top-down.

Comment: @JoWehler I'm actually rather intrigued by it.  We're so used to thinking of bottom-up and top-down, never do we consider bottom-down or top-up.

Comment: @Cort Ammon I apologize but I do not understand your comment. The original post uses the term "bottom-down" which is unknown to me.

Comment: @JoWehler Exactly my point.  We hear bottom-up and top-down all the time.  Nobody gives any thought to what bottom-down means.  Maybe it can actually have quite a useful meaning, one I'd never thought of before.

Comment: @Cort Ammon You too employ the term *bottom-down* in your answer. Hence I assume you know its meaning :-)

Comment: Philosophy does not work like this because language does not work like this. Frege, Carnapp, Russel early Wittgenstein and early Husserl are examples of philosophers that tried to establish similar structures, but failed. I wonder if this hybris will ever be realized in linguistics.

Comment: Btw I actually think the edit did make it worse, because now the question has nothing to do with its title anymore regarding the content and meaning. That is exactly why I did not follow the proposal.

Answer (score 6):

The philosophical concept you're looking for is *foundationalism*; it hasn't always been neccessary - after all arithmetic  was done and number theory pursued for two Millenia before a foundational movement took hold.

There are other foundations of mathematics; one that is growing in importance is based on category theory.

Philosophy has pretty much maintained an interest in Language from its beginnings; this being how we think things through; for example Aristotle begins his analysis of logic by looking how we concieve things in language.

But that there is more to mathematics than set theory, and there is more to philosophy than the philosophy of language - interesting though they are.

A quote from *The Republic (Book VI)* might prove useful here:

> **Socrates**: and when they are filling in the work, as I concieve, they will often turn their eyes *upwards* and *downwards*.

Comment: What does he mean by "they will turn their eyes upwards and downwards."?

Answer (score 3):

I would add to Mozibur's answer that several of the historically notable philosophers have tried to build complete philosophical systems from the ground up. Look at Kant and early Wittgenstein as examples. Indeed one could argue that attempts to build mathematics from the ground up the way Russell and Whitehead did was inspired partially by the philosophical tradition of building entire systems from a set of initial ontological and epistemic considerations.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to all the good answers above that, yes, *foundationalism,* or the ancient struggle to find the right starting point has been the regenerative force in philosophy. What is the most fundamental, indisputable basis upon which knowledge can construct itself? Experience? Clear and distinct ideas? Being? Language? Dialectical opposition?

Perhaps the most explicit, comprehensive effort in this direction comes in Hegel's *Science of Logic* and other works, wherein he attempts to build a complete philosophical system out of philosophical systems and a "logic" of logics. He observes first that there can be no "correct" starting point, one must simply slip into a phenomenological-hermeneutical circle of sorts and build outwards... and inwards.

It is well worth reading the opening of his *Logic*, where he "begins" with "Being" and demonstrates how it passes by itself into "Nothing" to generate, through the *Aufhebung,* the movement of "Becoming." The is not unlike physics finding that it could never reach the bottommost "particle," but only a kind of oscillating indeterminacy out of which particles arise... or perhaps the paradoxes in mathematics relating to zero and infinity.

Many agree that Hegel's was the last attempt at founding a comprehensive philosophical system, and many more considered it the paradigm of mental folly. Strangely, Hegel never did develop a philosophy of language. And the next wave of "foundationalism" then turned to language and logic with Frege, Russell, and others, where set theory became the area hope of placing everything of a "firm basis." I believe most people now think such a system would be an impossible or useless verbal construction.

I would take the lesson from Hegel that "top-down" or "bottom-up" architectures must, at the very least, be reconceived as a more organic "inside-out" and "outside-in" reproduction of thinking, one that abhors closure and thus advances like Sisyphus towards its own ever-retreating "foundations."

Answer (score 1):

Both philosophy and mathematics are constructed with both bottom-up and top-down constructions.  Philosophy does contain the "bottom-down" constructs you mention, but it also has more traditional structures, such as its handling of logic.  Meanwhile, there is a field called "reverse mathematics" which is the mathematical process of trying to determine how to arrive at an a proven statement with as few assumptions as possible.

And then there's Hofstadter's "Strange Loops," curious mathematical oddities, where you can create a clear hierarchical structure, only to find yourself looped back to where you began.  They might be an example of a place where the line between mathematics and philosophy gets quite murky.